# Azure sandbox resource group not visible

Tags: azure

I tried following [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/azure-architecture-fundamentals/exercise-create-website) on Azure.  It created a sandbox resource group for me called `learn-30262576-0bfb-433d-b6f8-b8fa7dd69a9d` but this group does not appear in my account in the portal.  I have no filters, subscription==all and location==all.  I have only one Microsoft account and I'm signed in with the same email address on both sites.

So continuing the exercise, I created my own resource group, app service, configured launched Wordpress, etc.  Now I have a public Wordpress URL but the exercise won't let me pass, presumably because it's looking for my Wordpress in the wrong resource group.

I waited 2 hours for the sandbox to expire, then made a new one and it has the same problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might want to check if you're in the right directory. Go to the Azure Portal, and log in. Click on your e-mail on the top-right:

[image]

Then click on Switch directory, and you'll get a list of directories you're in. There, by selecting Microsoft Learn Sandbox, you'll be switched to that directory, where you can see resources created by Learn.

[image: Azure directory + subscription list]

Comment: Thank you!  I must have missed the instructions about this, I did not know I have multiple directories.